# How to improve this algorithm for run-time efficiency?

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime, coding-efficiency

I recently had an assignment in my algorithms class. The problem statement is given below:

> Write and briefly explain the following C++ function: `int Sum (int *nums, int len);` that accepts an integer array, nums, containing len > 0 positive integers, and returns the sum closest to 330 that was found by adding up to three integers in the array (where each element of the array can only be included once in the sum).
>   For example, if [nums] contains [10 100 200 2] and len==4, the function returns
>   310=200+100+10. If [nums] contains [10 100 230 2] and len==4, the function returns 330=100+230.

My attempt at the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Description: function to find the sum closed to 330 by adding up
 *              to 3 integers
 * Arguments  : nums - integer array
 *              len  - length of integer array
 * Return     : sum closest to 330
 */
int Sum (int *nums, int len)
{
    const int number = 330;
    /* variable to store sum closest to 330 */
    int closest_sum = 0;
    /* variable to store difference of sum from 330 */
    int diff = INT_MAX;
    /* iterate over the integer array to find the sum closest to 330 */
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        /* temporary variable to hold sum of integers */
        int sum = 0;
        /* set first of 3 numbers as the sum */
        sum = nums[i];
        /* if the first number is equal to 330, no need to move forward; */
        /* return 330 */
        if(abs(number - sum) == 0) return number;
        /* compare the absolute difference of sum and 330 with previous */
        /* difference */
        if(abs(number - sum) < diff)
        {
            /* if current difference is less than previous difference, */
            /* update diff and set closest sum to current sum */
            diff = abs(number - sum);
            closest_sum = sum;
        }
        /* include the second of 3 numbers */
        for(int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
        {
            /* set sum as the addition of the first 2 numbers */
            sum = nums[i] + nums[j];
            /* if the sum is equal to 330, no need to move forward; */
            /* return 330 */
            if(abs(number - sum) == 0) return number;
            /* compare the absolute difference of sum and 330 with previous */
            /* difference */
            if(abs(number - sum) < diff)
            {
                /* if current difference is less than previous difference, */
                /* update diff and set closest sum to current sum */
                diff = abs(number - sum);
                closest_sum = sum;
            }
            /* include the third of 3 numbers */
            for(int k = j + 1; k < len; k++)
            {
                /* set sum as the addition of the 3 numbers */
                sum = nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k];
                /* if the sum is equal to 330, no need to move forward; */
                /* return 330 */
                if(abs(number - sum) == 0) return number;
                /* compare the absolute difference of sum and 330 with */
                /* previous difference */
                if(abs(number - sum) < diff)
                {
                    /* if current difference is less than previous */
                    /* difference, update diff and set closest sum to current */
                    /* sum */
                    diff = abs(number - sum);
                    closest_sum = sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* return closest sum to 330 */
    return closest_sum;
}

int main() {
    const int len = 6;
    int arr[len] = {300, 320, 310, 500, 5, 330};
    cout << "Closest to 330:\t" << Sum(arr, len) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code works correctly and passed all test cases that the grader used. However, part of the marks were related to the efficiency of the code. I lost points because the run-time of the code is ϴ(n^3) (because of the three nested `for` loops).

My question is: how can this algorithm be improved to be more efficient i.e. with a run-time less than ϴ(n^3)?

EDIT: Just to make it clear, up until the time when this assignment was due, we had only studied arrays/vectors, asymptotic notation, recursion/recurrence time in class. I am pretty sure we were not expected to use heaps, binary search (which, in fact, we will be studying next week), sorting algorithms etc. **Also**, please notice that the question says **up to three integers**, i.e. the closest sum to 330 can be made up of 1 number, 2 numbers or 3 numbers. I have to take in to account all these possibilities.

Comment: @MitchWheat we had not studied max-heaps until like 2 weeks after this assignment was due. Therefore, I don't think we were expected to use them.

Comment: Please put your code in the question, in order to make this Q&A self sufficient. Otherwhise this question might become useless to the community once the pastebin content vanishes

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit? [Code should be included in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you don't plan on adopting any of the techniques suggested here simply because you have yet to study them, then this brute force strategy is the only one you can use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to improve working code belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you first sort your numbers, you can have a nested loop that tests every pair of numbers, and selects the third number using a binary search.

the complexity of this algorithm is O(N^2 * log(N)), (plus N log(N) for the sorting)

Comment: With sorted numbers, you can also skip all numbers larger than 330.

Comment: @Sebastian, See edit in original question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your instructor might be thinking of a *wrong* answer.

You can use two loops to generate a vector of all pair sums, and then use another two loops to add a third number to those. This "avoids" a third level of nesting.

This answer is *wrong*, however, because the length of the generated vector is O(N^2). This gives you an O(N) loop inside an O(N^2) loop, making the complexity of the two loops combined O(N^3)

The root cause of your problem here is that there are indeed N^3 possible sums. Even if you take into account the 3! different orders in which you can add three numbers, any solution that considers all possible triplets must be O(N^3). Any better solution must skip some sums outright. Sebastia'n's existing answer skips some of those sums by sorting the input, so you can eliminate a large set of possibilities by a log(N) binary search. But with just a plain regular vector, you cannot skip any input.

There are a few tricks that will improve the *expected* runtime, but only by a constant. For instance, you can calculate the minimum and maximum value of the input in O(N). You can then simplify the problem by subtracting the minimum from all inputs, and 3*the minimum from the target value. I.e the problem `[10 100 200 2] => 330` simplifies to `[8 98 198 0] = > 324`. The advantage of having a maximum is that you might be able to skip the inner loop for *some* pairs. After adding `8+0`, it's clear that even adding the maximum `198` will only get you to 206, which will be worse than the best result you will have at that point.

Comment: @user3386109: Well, the target sum is only 330, so you can pre-compute all possible triplets that add up to 330, 329, etc. Formally that is an O(1) sized list, even though it has several million members. And by treating the elements as 3-digit number in base 330, lookup can be O(1).

Comment: constructing that list is O(N^3)

Comment: @SebastiánMestre: Nope. N is the number of the input arguments here (`int len`), and the construction is an input-independent pre-calculation.

Comment: ah. i see what you mean